# Map key not found error despite using option classes

Tags: scala

I'm new to the concept of using the Option type but I've tried to use it multiple places in this class to avoid these errors.

The following class is used to store data.

```
class InTags(val tag35: Option[String], val tag11: Option[String], val tag_109: Option[String], val tag_58: Option[String])
```

This following code takes a string and converts it into a Int -> String map by seperating on an equals sign.

```
      val message= FIXMessage("8=FIX.4.29=25435=D49=REDACTED56=REDACTED115=REDACTED::::::::::CENTRAL34=296952=20151112-17:11:1111=Order7203109=CENTRAL1=TestAccount63=021=155=CSCO48=CSCO.O22=5207=OQ54=160=20151112-17:11:1338=5000040=244=2815=USD59=047=A13201=CSCO.O13202=510=127
")
       val tag58 =  message.fields(Some(58)).getOrElse("???")
        val in_messages= new InTags(message.fields(Some(35)), message.fields(Some(11)), message.fields(Some(109)), Some(tag58))
        println(in_messages.tag_109.getOrElse("???"))
```

where the FIXMessage object is defined as follows:

```
class FIXMessage (flds: Map[Option[Int], Option[String]]) {
  val fields = flds

  def this(fixString: String) = this(FIXMessage.parseFixString(Some(fixString)))

  override def toString: String = {
    fields.toString
  }
}
object FIXMessage{
  def apply(flds: Map[Option[Int], Option[String]]) = {
    new FIXMessage(flds)
  }

  def apply(flds: String) = {
    new FIXMessage(flds)
  }

  def parseFixString(fixString: Option[String]): Map[Option[Int], Option[String]] = {
     val str = fixString.getOrElse("str=???")
      val parts = str.split(1.toChar)
      (for {
        part <- parts
        p = part.split('=')
      } yield Some(p(0).toInt) -> Some(p(1))).toMap
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is `ERROR key not found: Some(58)` but doesnt the option class handle this? Which basically means that the string passed into the FIXMessage object doesnt contain a substring of the format `58=something`(which is true) What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: I think you could use the `Map` type a bit differently and achieve better design. Couldn't you use a `Map[Int, Option[String]]` instead that only holds data if a key exists? You could do `myMap.get(58)` and play with an `Option[Option[String]]`? Outer option tells you there is a key or not, inner option tells you if there's a value or not.

Comment: I'm not seeing much point in saving your Map keys and values as Options. It usually makes more sense to save real key/values and use Map methods that return Options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `apply` method in `Map`, which returns the value or throw `NoSuchElementException` if key is not present.

Instead you could use `getOrElse` like

```
message.fields.getOrElse(Some(58), Some("str"))
```

Comment: I just figured this out as you typed it! This ended up fixing it for me
val tag58 =  message.fields.getOrElse(Some(58), None)

Comment: @Zee `fields.get(Some(58))` is the same as `fields.getOrElse(Some(58), None)`